# In iOS7, why selected cell's background color is always gray?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, background, ios7

set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`, or even manually set **Blue** in storyboard, but neither of them works.

if using `setSelectedBackgroundView:`, it may work.

But I really want to know why method of `[cell setSelectionStyle:] not work any more in iOS 7? Is it deprecated in iOS 7? If so, why no any waring in Xcode when typing?

Answer (score 5):

The method is not deprecated, and it still works—try setting a cell’s `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`, for instance. In iOS 7, though, the previous default—`UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`—now looks like the new default, i.e. gray.