# UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` for the cell selection style. But whatever style I set it only displays `UITableViewCellSelectionStylegray`. I am using Xcode 5.

This is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *cellid = @"Table1";
     UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
     if (cell==Nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];
     }

     cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

     cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbgimg.png"] ;

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Using which Xcode version is not the main focus. The question should be, which base iOS SDK you are using. Also, please show your related codes.

Comment: hi thankz for ur response. my base sdk is ios 7.1

Comment: It appears that as of iOS 7 the blue option either doesn't work or looks like gray.  See this previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304410/in-ios7-why-selected-cells-background-color-is-always-gray .  I have the same problem.  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone works but the other choices Blue/Gray/Default all look gray.  Evidently Apple itself no longer uses this feature or they would have fixed it.

Comment: Problem is nothing, just move ur selectionstyle code line paste it before return cell;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i am able to change the `UITableviewSelectionStyleBlue`. Please try below code:

```
// take a view for the cell...

UIView *cellBg = [[UIView alloc] init];
cellBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // this RGB value for blue color
cellBg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
Cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBg;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one ....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" ForIndexpath:indexPath];
   }
   [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue]; // This one for your cell selection style.

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think u r not working with cocoa. Please check again and again.otherwise share your code

Comment: i have tried the above code. But it still display UITableViewCellSelectionStylegray. i m entirely new to ios. so plz help me out to sort this problem.

even i tried UITableViewCellSelectionStyleblue in -tableView: willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: but its not displaying in blue